# Database table design containing different html form fields

Tags: html, mysql, database, jsp

Suppose I have two forms.
Form 1
[image]

Form 2
[image]

I want to store these form fields in database so that I can dynamically generate required form  from single jsp page. There is a particular order of input fields according to each form. Consider two buttons. When I click button1, Form1 is generated taking corresponding input fields from database and same for form2.

Also there will be checkboxes and select statements with multiple options. I want to store them as well.
There will be some common fields and some different fields in both the forms.

I only want idea how I design flexible database schema for it so that in future more forms can be added.

Comment: Please lookup "how to ask a question" on stackoverflow for helpful information about how to ask a question that will get useful answers, and the types of questions allowed on SO.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Ok I will take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you structure your program for creating schema and storing form detail into database.

I recommend,

Create database from JSP code and then generated form using data inside table from JSP as well. For it, you have to create preferences table where you can insert form schema detail and when form page upload it always generate **form** using tables data.

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/demo/build-mysql-tables.php. You have to build multiple tables based upon your needs

Comment: I mentioned my needs in question and I am not getting you.